# Converting boost controller to sync boost controller using H-bridge or 2 gate drivers

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, h-bridge, led-driver, synchronous

I am trying to reduce power losses in a boost led driver. For example TPS92690, uses a MOSFET and a diode for boost mode. Is it a bad idea to use H-bridge instead, or two gate drivers (one in straight and one in reversed modes) with 2 MOSFETS, so one signal from controller will drive 2 MOSFETS like in synchronous converters?

I need to drive 5A led. The diode will dissipate 0.5V*5A=2.5W power, is it right? I assume a MOSFET will dissipate less.

Comment: I do not like "is it possible" questions as a valid answer to that is "yes: or "no". If I'd answer "no" then the next day someone else could disprove my answer by doing it anyway. So I'll play safe and say "yes", but then you should explain **why** that would improve power losses. Trying to improve efficiency by "just assuming"  a certain cause, isn't good engineering. Maybe something else is going on. The TPS92690 isn't designed for an H-bridge so why use one?

Comment: You are right. As I am not experienced enough in electronics I ask dumb questions. I need to drive 5A led. The diode will dissipate 0.5V*5A=2.5W power, is it right? I assume a MOSFET will dissipate much less.

Comment: Depending on the type of diode, 2.5 W at 5 A should be about correct. But if there's 5 A going into the LEDs and assuming you use many LEDs in series (for higher voltage and better efficiency) then those LEDs will consume much, much more power than 2.5 W. What matters is **efficiency** so how much power is lost **relative** to the output power.